# How to select distinct values from ORMlite?

Tags: android, ormlite

I want to get distinct values from Database. Currently I am using ORMlite. I have tried the following code. But still I am getting repeated values from, when I am querying. Could anyone point out where I have gone wrong? I am posting the sample code below

```
smsDao = databaseHelper.getSmsDao();
    QueryBuilder<SMSObject, Object> queryBuilder = smsDao.queryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.distinct().selectColumns("timestamp");

    try {
        preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        smsObject = smsDao.query(preparedQuery);
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 dataList = Utils.getDBHelper(ItemList.this).getItemDao().queryBuilder().where().in("nameid", lis).query();
```

This is the code I used earlier in my app. It was retrieving duplicate values from the database. Then I updated it with the distinct() method and everything started to work fine.

```
 dataList = Utils.getDBHelper(ItemList.this).getItemDao().queryBuilder().distinct().where().in("nameid", lis).query();
```

Note: Here 'lis' is the iteratable list in which my search parameters are added. If you don't have one, you can use 'eq()' instead of 'in()'.